# Induction Principle for Propositions with Lists (or: LNR for expressions with nested lists)

Tags: coq, induction

Disclaimer: I fear this post got quite long, however, I feel that in a smaller setup some valuable background information would be lost.

I am currently trying to change my formalisation to use the locally nameless representation by Charguéraud et al [1]. Apparently, this adaption is not as straightforward as I hoped because my definition of expressions contains lists (at least I currently think this is the main problem).

So, I have the following (minimal) definition of expressions.

```
Require Import Coq.Lists.List.
Require Import Coq.Arith.PeanoNat.

Parameter atom : Set.
Parameter eq_atom_dec : forall x y : atom, {x = y} + {x <> y}.

Definition VarIndex := nat.

Inductive Expr : Type :=
 | BVar : VarIndex -> VarIndex -> Expr
 | FVar : atom -> Expr
 | LetB : list Expr -> Expr -> Expr.
```

With this definition at hand I can define the opening operation.

```
Fixpoint open_rec (k: VarIndex) (u: list Expr) (e: Expr) :=
  match e with
  | BVar i j => if Nat.eq_dec k i then List.nth j u e else e
  | FVar x => e
  | LetB es e' => LetB (List.map (open_rec (S k) u) es) (open_rec (S k) u e')
  end.

Notation "{ k ~> u } t" := (open_rec k u t) (at level 67).

Definition open e u := open_rec 0 u e.
```

So far so good. Next the property of being "locally closed" is defined inductively as follows.

```
Inductive lc : Expr -> Prop :=
| lc_var : forall x,
    lc (FVar x)
| lc_let : forall (ts: list Expr) es e,
    Forall lc es ->
    lc (open e ts) ->
    lc (LetB es e).
```

The tutorial now states that we can proof a lemma about the interaction of `lc` and `open`, i.e. in a locally closed expressions nothing happens when we substitute a variable.

```
(* this is a auxiliary lemma that works just fine for me *)
Lemma open_rec_lc_core : forall e (j: VarIndex) v (i: VarIndex) u,
    i <> j ->
    {j ~> v} e = {i ~> u} ({j ~> v} e) ->
    e = {i ~> u} e.
Proof.
Admitted.

Lemma open_rec_lc0 : forall k u e,
    lc e ->
    e = {k ~> u} e.
Proof.
  intros k u e LC.
  generalize dependent k.
  induction LC; intro k.
  - reflexivity.
  - simpl.
    f_equal.
    + admit.
    + eapply open_rec_lc_core with (j := 0).
      * auto.
      * eapply IHLC.         
Admitted.
```

As you can see, there is a case that is "admitted" in the proof. The problem here is that I have to proof something about the let-bindings, but everything I have at hand is the following:

```
H : Forall lc (map (fun e' : Expr => open e' ts) es)
LC : lc (open e ts)
IHLC : forall k : VarIndex, open e ts = {k ~> u} open e ts
```

What I need is an equivalent hypothesis to IHLC but for `es`.
My first guess was that I need to modify the induction principle as it is usually done[2] for inductive definitions with lists as arguments.
However, I cannot workout a definition that actually type checks.

```
Fail Definition lc_ind2 :=
  fun (P : Expr -> Prop) (f : forall x : atom, P (FVar x))
    (f0 : forall (ts es : list Expr) (e : Expr),
        Forall lc (map (fun e' : Expr => open e' ts) es) ->
        lc (open e ts) -> P (open e ts) ->
        Forall P (map (fun e' => open e' ts ) es) ->
        P (LetB es e)) =>
    fix F (e : Expr) (l : lc e) {struct l} : P e :=
    match l in (lc e0) return (P e0) with
    | lc_var x => f x
    | lc_let ts es e0 f1 l0 =>
      f0 ts es e0 f1 l0 (F (open e0 ts) l0)
         ((fix F' (es: list Expr) : Forall P es :=
                     match es with
                     | nil => Forall_nil P
                     | cons x xs => Forall_cons x (F x _) (F' xs)
                     end) (map (fun e' => open e' ts) es))
    end.
```

Instead of `_` in the application of `Forall_cons` I need something of type `lc x`, but I do not know how to come up with this value.

So, in the end my question is, if someone has an idea which definitions I need to modify in order to work with the LNR.

[1] [Tutorial on LNR](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~plclub/popl08-tutorial/code/coqdoc/STLC_Tutorial.html)
[2] [Induction principles with list arguments](http://adam.chlipala.net/cpdt/html/InductiveTypes.html#lab32)

Comment: What is `VarIndex`?

Comment: Oh, sorry, it's just a renaming for `nat`, but thanks for spotting that, I edited the post.

Comment: (1) Why does `BVar` have 2 indices? What do they mean informally? (2) What does `LetB` represent informally?

Comment: (1) is a consequence of (2). `LetB` represents multiple let-bindings à la "let x = 31; y = x + 2" and `BVar i j` has two indices to handle exactly these binders. The `i` says how many binders you have to pass in order to get to your declaration and in case of a let-binder the `j` says which of these multi-binders to take (for example, `1` for x and `2` for y in the above let-expression). The approach was also discussed in Chapter 7.2 by [Charguéraud](http://www.chargueraud.org/research/2009/ln/main.pdf).

Comment: @ichistmeinname I am interested by the proof of `open_rec_lc_core`, how did you prove it ?

Comment: @eponier Sorry for the late response; I created a [gist](https://gist.github.com/ichistmeinname/4f39ce693d566459ba580f7131f4d41f).

Comment: @ichistmeinname Thank you. I wanted to see if the proof required some trick about nested induction, but it is not the case. I don't understand really why.

Comment: @eponier Which part of the lemma did make you think of nested induction?

Comment: @ichistmeinname Nothing in particular. But it seemed to involve induction about `e`, which is a nested inductive type ; and the proof manipulates `Forall` and `map`, which often needs an induction. That's why I expected nested induction, and something complicated involving a `fix` inside a `fix`. Here, a normal induction inside a normal induction is sufficient. And I do not understand why it's enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution that works. I do not understand all the details. For instance, in the first proof, the induction must be done on the `Forall` hypothesis directly, not on `es` to respect the guard condition. Also note the use of `refine`, which lets build a term iteratively, by leaving underscores to yet unknown arguments and completing gradually.

```
Lemma lc_ind2 : forall P : Expr -> Prop,
  (forall x : atom, P (FVar x)) ->
  (forall (ts es : list Expr) (e : Expr),
  Forall lc es -> Forall P es ->
  lc (open e ts) -> P (open e ts) -> P (LetB es e)) ->
  forall e : Expr, lc e -> P e.
Proof.
  intros. revert e H1.
  refine (fix aux e H1 (* {struct H1} *) := match H1 with
  | lc_var x => H x
  | lc_let ts es e HFor Hlc => H0 ts es e HFor _ Hlc (aux (open e ts) Hlc)
  end).
  induction HFor.
  constructor.
  constructor.
  apply aux. apply H2. assumption.
Qed.

Lemma Forall_map : forall {A} f (l:list A),
  Forall (fun x => x = f x) l ->
  l = map f l.
Proof.
  intros.
  induction H.
  reflexivity.
  simpl. f_equal; assumption.
Qed.

Lemma open_rec_lc0 : forall k u e,
    lc e ->
    e = {k ~> u} e.
Proof.
  intros k u e H. revert k u.
  induction H using lc_ind2; intros.
  - reflexivity.
  - simpl. f_equal.
    + apply Forall_map. apply Forall_forall. rewrite Forall_forall in H0.
      intros. apply H0. assumption.
    + eapply open_rec_lc_core with (j := 0).
      * auto.
      * eapply IHlc.
Qed.
```

Comment: I finally took the time to adapt your approach in my current setting and it works perfectly! I didn't know how `refine` works before, so thank you for introducing me to a new tactic. This is definitely helpful in the future as well.

Answer (score 3):

Okay, so in the end I just inlined the `Forall` into a local inductive definition that uses `lc`.

```
Inductive lc : Expr -> Prop :=
| lc_var : forall x,
    lc (FVar x)
| lc_let : forall (ts: list Expr) es e,
    Forall_lc es ->
    lc (open e ts) ->
    lc (LetB es e).
with Forall_lc : list Expr -> Prop :=
     | nil_lc : Forall_lc nil
     | cons_lc : forall e es, lc e -> Forall_lc es -> Forall_lc (e :: es).
```

And generated the induction principle I need.

```
Scheme lc2_ind := Minimality for lc Sort Prop
  with lc_Forall_ind := Minimality for Forall_lc Sort Prop.
```

The same approach was taken [here (Chapter 4)](http://biblioteca.sistedes.es/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/PROLE-2012-15-A-formalization-in-Coq-of-Launchburys-natural-semantics-for-lazy-evaluation.pdf).
I guess, in the end, the trick is to use mutually recursive definitions instead of trying to apply `lc` as a parameter to `Forall`.

Comment: Actually I am trying to formalise a functional logic programming language, but the `let`-part is indeed just a functional component! : )

Comment: i remember that i formalized the let with a list of pairs , each node represent a correspondence between a ident and a lamba term